# Can You help me to find a greedy algorithm for covering a line segment?

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization

The Question is :Given n segments of line (into the X axis) with coordinates [Li , Ri](coordinates could be negative numbers). You are to choose the minimum number of segments that cover the whole segment [0 , M].

And Here What I did: Actually I've Sorted the segments by their starting coordinates (Li) in increasing order. Then Selected the segments starting with the smallest Li and then selected the Largest one.

but my algorithm does not work for some instances. Do You Guys Have any other idea for this problem ? please give me some hints for solving this problem.

Comment: It is rather simple problem, typical homework (note that you know that greedy algo does work). Your approach is not quite clear, please give us more details.

Answer (score 1):

First remove the segments having`R < 0`. Among the remaining segments, you must select at least one segment such that `L <= 0 <= R`. There is no loss in selecting the segment with the largest `R` among the segments having `L <= 0`.
Rinse and repeat with `[R, M]` instead of `[0, M]`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sort the segments by increasing Li.
2. Let L= 0, the leftmost abscissa to be covered.
3. Scan the list as long as Li <= L, while remembering the segment with the largest Ri.
4. Set L= Ri and continue the scan (3) where you left it, unless the list is exhausted.

The invariant of the main loop says "the segments already scanned minimally cover [0, L], and the remaining segments cover [L, M] (though not minimally)".

Comment: An improvement is to insert the segments in a heap instead of sorting them. Another option if they are sorted is to use binary search to find the last Li such that Li <= L.

Comment: @Gribouillis Binary search can be much worse than sequential: every search will cost Log(K) where K is the number of remaining elements; in the worst case (and probably the average case), O(N Log N) complexity. Sequential search is guaranteed O(N).

Comment: @Gribouillis: how will you use the heap (other than performing HeapSort) ?

Comment: My idea is that the only feature needed by the algorithm is *pull segment with lowest Li*. That's why i thought about a priority queue. Concretely however, there is probably no noticeable gain to obtain out of this.

Comment: About the binary search, it all depends on the sizes of the segments. For example if the average segment's length is a fixed value such as M/100, the size of the optimal covering is typically 200 for example. This is independent from the number N of segments. In that case I'll do a fixed number of searches, each having Log(N) complexity.

Comment: @Gribouillis: then you ARE performing a sort.

Comment: @Gribouillis: my bet is that in most practical situations, binary search would slow down the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting a python solution to this problem.

```
def calculateOptimizedPoint(numOfCordinates, cordinates):
     sortedCordinate = sorted((cordinate for cordinate in cordinates), key = lambda itm:itm[0])
     points = []
     currentRange = sortedCordinate[0][1]
     points.append(currentRange)
     for i in range(numOfCordinates-1):
         if (currentRange < sortedCordinate[i][0]) or currentRange > sortedCordinate[i][1]):
              currentRange = sortedCordinate[i][1]
              points.append(currentRange)
     return points

numOfCordinates = int(input("How many coordinate you want to input : "))
cordinates = [(int(input("Enter the a{} cordinate".format(i))),int(input("Enter the b{} cordinate".format(i)))) for i in range(numOfCordinates)]

print(calculateOptimizedPoint(numOfCordinates,cordinates))
```